# Expected declarations,Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'の原因

Tags: swift

BGMを再生するアプリを作成したいと思い、手始めにAVFoundationをインポートし、do-try-catch構文を使ってみようとしましたが、`Expected  declarations,Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'`が表示され、`;`を入力しても直らないため困っています。
解決策を教えてください。宜しくお願いします。

```
import AVFoundation //AVFoundationフレームワークをインポートする

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player:AVAudioPlayer? //音声を制御するための変数
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(soundName);do{
    try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:url)
    }catch{
    print("Error!")
}
}
```

Comment: Swiftは、コードの行末の`;`を省略できるのですが、それは言い換えると、見た目の改行がコードの行末になるわけで、適切なところで改行しないと、コンパイルをとおりません。いちど質問者さんご自身で、改行を取り直してみてください。

Answer (score 2):

あなたのコードを;を使わないように修正した上で、インデントしなおすとこのようになります。

```
import AVFoundation //AVFoundationフレームワークをインポートする

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player:AVAudioPlayer? //音声を制御するための変数
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(soundName)
    do {//<-このdo文がclass定義の直下にある
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:url)
    } catch {
        print("Error!")
    }
}
```

Swiftでは、do文のような実行文はclass定義の直下には書けません。また変数(?)soundNameも宣言されていないようです。必要なメソッドや変数を宣言し、実行文はメソッド内に記述してください。また、1行に複数の文を記述しようとすると構文上のエラーが見つけにくくなるので、慣れるまではできるだけ避けたほうが良いでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございました。言われた通りのコードを入力してみたところ上手くいきました。自分流のやり方だと、上手く行くときと行かないときが半々くらいなので仰られた通りのやり方でやっていこうと思います。